# Using a square from the html entities inside a hr

Tags: html, css, character-entities

I am styling my hr and for that,i am having this character `§` at the center.This is the code

```
hr.style-eight:after {
 content: "§";
 display: inline-block; 
position: relative;
 top: -0.7em;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 padding: 0 0.25em;
 background: white; 
}
```

I have looked at several character entities cheat sheets for a square character but nothing so far.Is there square character in the existing html or html5 entities that i can use or an alternative method in css3 that can produce the square?.

Comment: It is probable that the question title does not reflect the real problem, which seems to be “how do I put a character in a square” (which has many interesting approaches, so you should clarify the specific context).

Comment: Allow me to edit the question with new information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [HTML5 Character Entity Reference](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) (which you've supposedly already looked at):

```
□
&squ; &square; &Square;
&#x025A1;
&#9633;
```

There's also:

```
▪
&squf; &squarf; &blacksquare; &FilledVerySmallSquare;
&#x025AA;
&#9642;
```

Comment: I was looking at the w3schools set.This set http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp plus some other references online.

Comment: It is a pointless risk to use new character references like `&squ;` which are not supported by old browsers (unlike the numeric references).

Comment: I did the conversion here http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/08/css-javascript-character-entities/ and used the hex.It works.

Answer (score 2):

Use borders?

CSS

```
h1:after{
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GNCqx/)